# ios-charts - problems using autoScaleMinMaxEnabled

Tags: ios-charts

I try to auto scale the y-axis for an LineChart. If I set the option autoScaleMinMaxEnabled, followed by an notifyDataSetChanged no auto scale occurs.
Also toggeling autoScaleMinMaxEnabled in ChartsDemo seems not to work. Is there a special trick?

Many thanks! - Tino

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is that min/max of the Y-axis is determined dynamically, during scrolling, depending on the y-values that are contained in the visible x-range.

If you want to see it working in the demo, then zoom in, enable `autoScaleMinMaxEnabled`, and then scroll to the right. Watch the Y-axis.